# How can I loop through an array of objects using a 'for loop' and print the results in a template literal

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to loop through an array of objects using a 'for' loop, and want to print the results in a template using Javascript. However, the data in the template comes back as undefined. Not sure where I am going wrong?

```js
const people = [{
    name: "Martin",
    age: 45
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    age: 32
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let template = `
         <h2>${people.name}</h2>
         <p>${people.age}</p>
     `;
  document.write(template);
}
```

Comment: `people[i].name`

Comment: @adiga Thank you! I understand now. I just missed that bit. Suppose I have been using too much Vue.JS where you simply have something like {{person.name}} etc. Thanks for helping. It works and I now understand.

Answer (score 3):

You're not accessing the current element of the array instead your accessing `people.name` and `people.age` which are both undefined. You need to change it to:

```
for(let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    const template = `
         <h2>${people[i].name}</h2>
         <p>${people[i].age}</p>
     `;
     document.write(template);
}
```

Even simpler is to use a modern `for ... of`-loop:

```
for(const currPerson of people) {
    const template = `
         <h2>${currPerson.name}</h2>
         <p>${currPerson.age}</p>
     `;
     document.write(template);
}
```

Comment: Love the second approach. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the index (i.e. i) to access the people array item:

```
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Martin',
    age: 45,
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    age: 32,
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let person = people[i];
  let template = `
       <h2>${person.name}</h2>
       <p>${person.age}</p>
   `;
  document.write(template);
}
```